# Deploy Isomorphic react starter kit to AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, reactjs, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, react-starter-kit

I'm a newbie when it comes to Node.js nad React.

I'm trying to deploy [React Starter Kit — "isomorphic" web app boilerplate](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit) to the cloud. I'm currently using heroku, but I've read that I can do this using AWS Lambda and API gateway.
I tried to do this using [Serverless framework](https://serverless.com/) and also do this on my own but didn't succeed.

Running the serverless framework using a webpack plugin failed because my webpack file is written in ES6 and I don't know how to run babel before webpack (locally, I'm running babel-node that calls webpack).

As for doing this manually- I couldn't find instructions for the starter-kit setup - should I upload the entire folder to S3? how to define the lambda function? do I need to change something in my current code?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there isn't a direct way to use that isomorphic starter kit on Lambda. AWS Lambda and API Gateway can help you set up a serverless backend. And you can host your React app statically on S3. Here is a fork of the starter kit that you linked to, that does exactly that - [React Static Boilerplate](https://github.com/koistya/react-static-boilerplate)

There are ways to server side render your React app on Lambda but they are a bit cumbersome and not very straightforward. Here is an article outlining some basic aspects of it - [Rendering React with Amazon Lambda](https://medium.com/@devknoll/rendering-react-with-amazon-lambda-e4e85a788257#.6e9w9j48x)

Comment: Thanks. It would be too cumbersome at the moment to port our code to the Statis boilerplate, so we'll stick with heroku for now.